# Magento API 2.1 catalogProductRepositoryV1 - cannot submit price

Tags: magento2, product, api, bug

I am using **magento 2.0 API** catalogProductRepositoryV1 to **POST** my product to the magento. Below is my body. The problem that I am facing is that when I submit this product for the first time to create the product in magento the price does not gets submitted, although the product submission is successful(in the GUI, Price is a mandatory field while submitting a product however from API if I dont pass $price, it still submits the product). Then when I submit the same product again with same body as below, the price shows up in both GUI as well as api call from postman. Same behavior is there with PUT.

```
{
"product": {
  "Name": "TEST",
  "price": 4,
  "sku": "ABC",
  "status": 1,
  "attribute_set_id": "4",
  "custom_attributes": [
    {
      "attribute_code": "category_ids",
      "value": [
        "5"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Any Idea if this is a product bug or am I missing something or its a product bug?

I am using this URL : http://magento-url/index.php/rest/V1/products/

Comment: Facing the same problem after update